# About Node.js Promise then and return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm confused about Promise!

I use **Promise then** without return like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("1");
}).then((v1) => {
    console.log("v1");
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Time-consuming operation, for example: get data from database;
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(2)
        }, 3000);
    }).then((v11) => {
        console.log("v11");
    })
}).then((v2) => {
    console.log("v2")
});
```

I get this result **v1 v2 v11**.
Then, I use another way of writing, Like below:

```
 new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("1");
}).then((v1) => {
    console.log("v1");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(2)
        }, 3000)
    }).then((v11) => {
        console.log("v11");
    })
}).then((v2) => {
    console.log("v2")
});
```

I get another result **v1 v11 v2**.

Maybe, There is another case:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
resolve("1");
}).then((v1) => {
console.log("v1");
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(2)}, 3000)
}).then((v11) => {
    console.log("v11");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(2)}, 4000)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("v12")
    })
})
}).then((v2) => {
console.log("v2")
});
```

I get this result **v1 v11 v12 v2**

I can't understand the second **return**  I want to know why I get this result?

Comment: Did you expect a different result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be easier to understand the control flow if you actually print the values of the resolved promises and not only the names of the variables:

#### Version 1

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("1");
}).then((v1) => {
    console.log("v1:", v1);
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Time-consuming operation, for example: get data from database;
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(2)
        }, 3000);
    }).then((v11) => {
        console.log("v11:", v11);
    })
}).then((v2) => {
    console.log("v2:", v2)
});
```

#### Version 2

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("1");
}).then((v1) => {
    console.log("v1:", v1);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(2)
        }, 3000)
    }).then((v11) => {
        console.log("v11:", v11);
    })
}).then((v2) => {
    console.log("v2:", v2)
});
```

#### Version 3

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("1");
}).then((v1) => {
       console.log("v1:", v1);
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           setTimeout(() => {resolve(2)}, 3000)
       }).then((v11) => {
           console.log("v11:", v11);
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               setTimeout(() => {resolve(2)}, 4000)
           }).then((v12) => {
              console.log("v12:", v12)
           })
       })
 }).then((v2) => {
      console.log("v2:", v2)
 });
```

Now you can see what gets passed to the callbacks:

#### Result 1

```
v1: 1
v2: undefined
v11: 2
```

#### Result 2

```
v1: 1
v11: 2
v2: undefined
```

#### Result 3

```
v1: 1
v11: 2
v12: 2
v2: undefined
```

### Explanation

As you can see when in the `.then()` handlers you don't return a promise, it acts as if you returned an already resolved promise with value `undefined` - like if you did:

```
return Promise.resolve(undefined);
```

and thus the next `.then()` handler can be called immediately.

If, on the other hand, you return a promise that is not resolved yet, then the next `.then()` handler will not be invoked immediately but only after that returned promise gets resolved.

And that explains the order of execution that is different when you don't return a promise - and what happens is as if an already resolved promise got returned implicitly for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function one() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("one 1 ");
            resolve('one one');
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function two() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("two 2 ");
            resolve('two two');
        }, 10000);
    });
}

function three(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("three 3 ");
    }, 5000);
}

one().then((msg) => {
        console.log('one : ', msg);
        return two();
    }).then((msg) => {
        console.log('two :', msg);
        return three();
    }).then((msg) => {
        console.log('three :', msg);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Something bad happened:', error.toString());
    });
```

console three show undefined because three not parse resolve