# Microsoft Graph on-behalf-of token - is it one-use only?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm able to retrieve an on_behalf_of token from my backend API to use client-side in my page, but if I make two calls to the Microsoft Graph, one immediately after the other, the second one always fails with a 401 unauthorized. The calls are one straight after the other, so definitely within the expiry time window. Is this token one-use only (i.e. it's invalidated straight after use), or am I doing something wrong?

My code is based on [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs/blob/master/src/static/scripts/ssoDemo.js), but I've extended it to make another call immediately to the Graph again, as follows:

```
        function useServerSideTokenAgain(token) {

            display("4. Call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages with the server side token");

            return fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=sender,subject",
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json",
                        "authorization": "bearer " + token
                    },
                    mode: 'cors',
                    cache: 'default'
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.json();
                    } else {
                        throw (`Error ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
                    }
                })
                .then((profile) => {
                    display(JSON.stringify(profile, undefined, 4), 'pre');
                });
        }
```

then later on, I've changed from the original code:

```
 getClientSideToken()
                .then((clientSideToken) => {
                    return getServerSideToken(clientSideToken);
                })
                .then((serverSideToken) => {
                    return useServerSideToken(serverSideToken);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                ...
```

to this:

```
 getClientSideToken()
                .then((clientSideToken) => {
                    return getServerSideToken(clientSideToken);
                })
                .then((serverSideToken) => {
                    return useServerSideToken(serverSideToken);
                })
                .then((serverSideToken) => {
                    return useServerSideTokenAgain(serverSideToken);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                ...
```

My app has delegated "Mail.Read" rights, so the operation itself works fine. Incidentally, if I change the order of operations, the same thing happens in reverse (step 4 works fine, but step 3 throws a 401 unauthorized):

```
 getClientSideToken()
                ...
                .then((serverSideToken) => {
                    return useServerSideTokenAgain(serverSideToken);
                })
                .then((serverSideToken) => {
                    return useServerSideToken(serverSideToken);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                ...
```

Comment: Please share your code about "make two calls to the Microsoft Graph, one immediately after the other" so that we can try to repro it.

Comment: updated with a lot more detail

Comment: I don't think the `serverSideToken` in `.then((serverSideToken) => {return useServerSideTokenAgain(serverSideToken);})` is a valid access token (maybe it's null). Per my understanding, `serverSideToken` should be from the previous step. But you cannot get it from the first Graph call `return useServerSideToken(serverSideToken);`. For then and return usage you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140118/about-node-js-promise-then-and-return?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: ah no man, total faceplant moment !! Thanks @AllenWu, didn't think through that properly